# Windows Phone - Access to camera requires the ISV Camera Capability

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I am building a Windows Phone app which uses the camera. I have the code:

```
 private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

 if ((PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) ||
     (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing) == true))  {
     // Initialize the default camera.
     _photoCamera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera();

     //Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized
     _photoCamera.Initialized += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(OnPhotoCameraInitialized);

      //Set the VideoBrush source to the camera
      viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
  }
  else {
      // The camera is not supported on the device.
      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()  {
      // Write message.
          txtDebug.Text = "A Camera is not available on this device.";
      });

  }

}

private void OnPhotoCameraInitialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Width);
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(_photoCamera.PreviewResolution.Height);
}
```

And I keep getting the exception:
**"Access to camera requires the ISV Camera Capability."**

I have a `Lumia 900`, and I know it runs camera `APIs` (the sample form MS works fine). But when I go to put this code in my app, I get this exception. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? I am a good `C#`'er, but the Windows Phone is quite new to me.

Many thanks!
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved it**:
I had to add the line:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
```

to my `WMAppManifent.xml` file.